# Angular UI Alerts: Fade In and Fade Out not working

Tags: angularjs

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/NHThZWGANMcYYK8WtZM9?p=preview), I'm trying to fade in alerts when they are created, and fade out when they are closed (either manually or automatically). I'm using ng-animate, but the animation is ignored. Any ideas?

HTML

```
<style>
.fade.ng-enter {
  transition:0.5s linear all;
  opacity:0;
}

.fade.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity:1;
}

.fade.ng-leave {
  transition:0.5s linear all;
  opacity:1;
}
.fade.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity:0;
}
</style>
  <button ng-click="addAlert()">Add Alert</button>
  <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}"  data-ng-animate="'fade'"
         close="closeAlert($index)">
    {{alert.msg}}</alert>
```

Javascript

```
var app = angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap','ngAnimate']);
app.controller('ctl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.alerts = [];
  var count = 1;

  $scope.closeAlert = function(index) {
      $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
  };

  $scope.addAlert = function() {
      $scope.alerts.push ( { type: 'info', msg: 'Information Only ' + count++ } );

  };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use CSS classes for ngAnimate to understand how to animate element. You also should use some other class other then `fade` because it has fixed `opacity: 0` which we don't want.

So all together:

```js
angular.module('demo', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ngAnimate']).controller('DemoController', function($scope) {

  $scope.alerts = [];
  var count = 1;

  $scope.closeAlert = function(index) {
    $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
  };

  $scope.addAlert = function() {
    $scope.alerts.push({
      type: 'info',
      msg: 'Information Only ' + count++
    });

  };
});
```

```css
.alert-fade.ng-enter {
  transition: 0.5s linear all;
  opacity: 0;
}
.alert-fade.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
.alert-fade.ng-leave {
  transition: 0.5s linear all;
  opacity: 1;
}
.alert-fade.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.13/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.0.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container" ng-app="demo" ng-controller="DemoController">
  <button ng-click="addAlert()">Add Alert</button>

  <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" class="alert-fade" close="closeAlert($index)">
    {{alert.msg}}
  </alert>
</div>
```

Comment: One note: ui-bootstrap-tpls 0.14.0 introduced a breaking change documented here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/wiki/Migration-guide-for-prefixes. This means <alert> is now <div uib-alert> and that ng-class="'alert-' + alert.type" needs to be added for it to look right and function correctly.